# gpg, one email address has two keys

Tags: gnupg

Let's say that a user has 2 keys listed in the gpg key ring (i.e., 2 keys with the same Email address). How does one set which key of the 2 to use? The only input that I have is the email, and it is the same for the 2 keys.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to encrypt to one of the keys, you can specify the recipient using the fingerprint or long key ID, for example

```
gpg --recipient A999B7498D1A8DC473E53C92309F635DAD1B5517 --armor --encrypt
```

Comment: This also works for other tasks, like public key exports.